# Error editing swf file with rabcasm

Tags: swfobject

please Help me with this....

How can I add post data to URLRequest

```
  getlex              QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "navigateToURL")
  getglobalscope
  findpropstrict      QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "URLRequest")
  pushstring          "http://hladino.com/api/camera/upload.php"
  constructprop       QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "URLRequest"), 1
  pushstring          "_self"
  call                2
  pop
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the result of the attempt?  What error message are you receiving or what undesired behavior occurred?

Comment: The SWF was forzen :(

Comment: It never started or froze part way through?  Does it work without the parameters?  What context does the code run in?

Comment: Your load is successful! Freezes by clicking on a button, whose function is to send a request to API

Comment: Are you sure the application/page is not pausing in order to process the API request?

Comment: API is working....   I want to do this:
https://pastebin.com/u3yR0d9V